# Bootstrap not aligning in Mozilla like in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is how my project looks like in Mozilla: http://i58.tinypic.com/6fsbr7.jpg
This is how my project looks like in Chrome: http://i61.tinypic.com/2zgrgq0.png

As you can see the two buttons in the navigation bar are, in Chrome, placed like I wanted. But in Mozilla they overlap on the right. Why?

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
        <c:if test="${user == null }">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#myModal">Registration</button>
        </c:if>
            <c:if test="${user != null}">
                <a href="./LogoutController" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" style="margin-top: 7">Logout</a>
                <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Hi, ${user.firstName}</p>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${'Admin' eq user.DTYPE}">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 7">Create Seller</a>
            </c:if>
        <c:if test="${user == null}">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left"    data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#myModal2">Sign in</button>
        </c:if>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.jsp">
            <img src="stuff/logo.png" class="brand"></img>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Just one more thing. When I click the logo, which takes me to the home page(the one from ss) the buttons align left for a second before they go overlap right...

Comment: Did you use css? if yes pls add that. Take also a look at the pull- left of the sign in button. I think that huge space doesn't need to be there

Comment: I did not use my custom css in that part of code and the gap is there by accident when I was making the question...